# How to split a string with different separators

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string like: "fruit(apple, orange, banana)", and I want my program to return:

```
fruit apple orange banana
```

This is what I wrote:

```
String string = "fruit(apple, orange, banana)";
string = string.trim();
String[] array = string.split(", | \\) | \\(");
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: `string.splot`? Are you serious?

Comment: It may work if you use `split` instead of `splot`

Comment: split*. My god it's just a typing mistake, relax

Comment: It is insane, why so many downvotes?? Anyway, @KingOfTheHill take a look at my answer. That should work.

Comment: Overreaction at its best :P

Comment: That is ridiculous! Thank you both for your answers! At the end i used both to solve it!

Comment: haha..you are welcome :)

Comment: @Akash we can reduce the effect of overreaction a bit, can't we?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ already done :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there. With [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html) you can use a regular expression to split a given string around matches of the given regular expression. Try this, it should work:

```
String string = "fruit(apple, orange, banana)";
String[] array = string.split("[(,)]");
```

The elements of `array` may have spaces at the beginning or the end, which you can eliminate using this:

```
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i].trim();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using this regex instead:

```
String[] array = string.split("[,\\(\\)]");
```